# Detect objects inside closure (in Linux Swift)

Tags: swift

I have a lot of classes like:

```
class Dog {
  var name = ""
}
class Cat {
  var name = ""
}
```

And one class with closure inside method:

```
class Reader {
   func read(_ block: (() -> Void)) {
      block()
   }
}
```

After I change attributes of first objects inside closure:

```
let reader = Reader()
reader.read {
   dog.name = "Bob"
   cat.name = "Tom"
}
```

I need inside *dog* and *cat* objects get reference to *reader*.
How to do this?

PS:
Dog and Cat classes can be inherited from the some parent class with additional features

**Update 1:**

I need to get something like:

```
class Reader {
   func doSomething(_ value: String) {
      print(value)
   }
   func read(_ block: (() -> Void)) {
      block()
   }
}

class Dog {
  var name = "" {
     didSet {
        reader?.doSomething(name) //!!!!! Main needed feature
        // reader object with it unique name will be init later
     }
  }
}
```

When I change *name* attribute of Dog class inside *read* closure:

```
let reader = Reader()
reader.read {
   dog.name = "Bob"
}
```

reader?.doSomething(name) must be executed.

Comment: What do you mean with “get reference”? The normal way to do this by _composition_, that is let Reader have a Cat and Dog property or let them have a Reader property. Or let the closure take an argument of a protocol or class that Cat and Dog implements/inherits

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean, that from "reader" object I need to get "name" attributes of all Cat and Dog like objects.

Comment: This last comment seems to be the opposite question from the question in the body. For reader to have access to the objects, pass the objects to reader as a collection. For the objects to have access to the reader, pass the reader to the objects. It's unclear how "reader" applies to "set the name properties."

Comment: If your actual point is to have a list of every Dog and Cat in the system, then you will need to maintain that list yourself, either by adding them to the list when you create them manually, or having the initializer for Dog and Cat add themselves to some global list when they're created. There is no general solution to getting a list of every instance of a type in the system if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: @RobNapier I can't pass reader directly to objects. objects can communicate with reader only over closure.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "object can communicate with reader only over closure." Add a parameter to the closure, and pass the object you want. Closures are functions; they can accept parameters. (Its unclear what you mean here by "communicate.")

Comment: Perhaps the best way to explain the question is to include an example of what you would like to happen *after* your last code block (what code would come next that you would consider a passing test case?). What is `dog` and `cat` in there? I don't see those assigned anywhere.

Comment: @RobNapier done

Comment: If you have access to `reader` _and_ all objects (`cat`s and `dog`s) as well as "unique names" when you insider this closure why can't you do everything there (call `doSomething`)?

Comment: From question there is really hard to understand what are you trying to achieve (I mean real code, not cats and dogs). I'm 100% sure there is another more common way to achieve this.

Comment: @MaximKosov Because I need to execute .doSomething(name) only when I change name value inside closure

Comment: So call it like `reader.read { dog.name = "dog"; reader.doSomething(dog.name); }` It _is_ inside closure

Comment: @MaximKosov Yes, I can do so. But if I have a lot of "Dog" objects, I need the same number of "reader.doSomething(dog.name);" I want to achieve  the same result as you propose only without "reader.doSomething(dog.name);"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176769/discussion-between-sergey-di-and-maxim-kosov).

Comment: Create a function which do both - set name and call `doSomething`. This is what functions for, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean “without reader.doSomething(dog.name)” ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "reader.doSomething(dog.name)” must be inside Dog attribute observer (like didSet{}) and executed if dog.name changed inside reader.read closure

Comment: But if it is inside didSet it will be called anytime name property is changed, is that what you want? I thought it was only supposed to be called when Reader.read was called?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I need to execute "reader.doSomething(dog.name)" only when "Reader.read was called". Attribute observer was as example...

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the easiest way will be passing captured object to read function and use KVO for catching updated values:

```
class ReadableObject: NSObject {
    weak var reader: Reader?
}

class Reader: NSObject {
    private var observerContext = 0

    func doSomething(with value: Any?, of property: String) {
        print("value of \(property) modified to: '\(value ?? "")'")
    }

    func read(capturedObjects:[ReadableObject], block: (() -> Void)) {
        capturedObjects.forEach({ object in
            object.reader = self
            let properties = Mirror(reflecting: object).children.compactMap { $0.label }
            properties.forEach({ (property) in
                object.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: property, options: [.new], context: &observerContext)
            })
        })
        block()
        capturedObjects.forEach({$0.reader = nil})
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &observerContext, let kp = keyPath, let obj = object as? ReadableObject else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }

        let value = obj.value(forKeyPath: kp)
        let className = NSStringFromClass(type(of: obj)).components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? ""
        obj.reader?.doSomething(with: value, of: "\(className).\(kp)")
    }
}
```

Then inherit your classes from `ReadableObject` and mark all readable properties as "@obj dynamic" (in order to make them observable).

```
class Dog: ReadableObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
}

class Cat: ReadableObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
}
```

Usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let reader = Reader()
        let dog = Dog()
        let cat = Cat()
        reader.read(capturedObjects: [dog, cat]) {
            dog.name = "Bob"
            cat.name = "Tom"
        }
    }
}
```

Console log:

> value of Dog.name modified to: 'Bob'
>   value of Cat.name modified to: 'Tom'

=========================
EDIT

If you don't want to use KVO then the alternative will be the usage of `didSet` block:

```
class Dog: ReadableObject {
    var name: String = "" {
        didSet {
            if let reader = reader { //If reader is not nil, then the property was modified inside "read" block
                reader?.doSomething(with: name, of: "Dog.name")
            }
        }
    }
}

class Cat: ReadableObject {
    var name: String = "" {
        didSet {
            if let reader = reader {
                reader?.doSomething(with: name, of: "Cat.name")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solutions is good, And KVO is what I try to use first. But KVO is not fully supported in Linux, i mean: " @objc dynamic var name: String = "" " return error in Linux swift: "Swift structs cannot be represented in Objective-C"

Comment: You should mention in your question that you're on Linux OS :)

Comment: The alternative will be using of swift's didSet block

Comment: I have added in subject that it is in Linux. You propose "didSet", but how to execute it only if value changed inside closure?